# Right side of image not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

How come only the left side of the play image is clickable?

https://jsfiddle.net/g8p1z2m0/

To reproduce Right mouse click on the right side of the play image, nothing happens.

Why is this happening and how is it fixed?

The whole play image should be clickable.

That is the whole issue I am having.

Nothing happens when clicking on the right side of the play image.

```js
(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
     
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".container");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketa");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curtain.slide {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
   display: block !important;
}
.j1 .jacketa {
  left: 30px;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 30px;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.container {
  height: auto;
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
 left: -500%;
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  left: 500%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">

      <div class="container hide">
        <div class="container-top">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-left"> </div>
      <div class="panel-right"> </div>

      <div class="split-wrap">
        <div class="j1">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j2">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll(".jacketa")` as it has 2 div elements with class `jacketa`. In your example it return the left part div container inside `<div class="j1">`.

> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the Dom tree that matches the specified selector.

```js
(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
     
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".container");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  const covers = document.querySelectorAll(".jacketa");
  covers.forEach(cover => cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler));
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curtain.slide {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
   display: block !important;
}
.j1 .jacketa {
  left: 30px;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 30px;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.container {
  height: auto;
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
 left: -500%;
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  left: 500%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">

      <div class="container hide">
        <div class="container-top">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-left"> </div>
      <div class="panel-right"> </div>

      <div class="split-wrap">
        <div class="j1">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j2">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change something in your JS.

instead of querying jacketmeta `const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketa");` you could change it to `const cover = document.querySelector(".split-wrap");`

Here's your working code https://codepen.io/mcfaith9/pen/VwbzqXP?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you only add the event to the left side. Both sides have the class `.jacketa` but you only do this:

```js
const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketa");
cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
```

in this case he only adds the listener to the first element he selects, to make it work on both elements you have to do this:

```js
const covers = document.querySelectorAll(".jacketa");
covers.forEach( cover => cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler) );
```